# How to use different properties file or environment profiles to execute a maven project?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, environment-variables, ui-automation, properties-file

I am building an automation framework to test a web application in 2 separate environments namely stage and test.
I am storing environment variables like "user_names" and "application_URL" which are unique to the environments in a property file which is read by the test scripts.
Since I have two different environments, i want to execute the same tests in both of them by having two separate profiles of environment variables files.

I have first environment properties file as below:-

```
browser = Chrome
admin_Url = https://stage-some-website/login
Username = adminuser1
Password = adminuserpw1
DatabaseURl=""
DatabasePasswords=""
```

This file is read by below base case which will initialize the browsers and read this property file.

```
public static WebDriver driver;
public static Properties read_propertyFile;
String PropertyFilePath = "\\src\\test\\java\\com\\resources\\Environment.properties";
```

If i make another property file for second environment, how can i use it ?

Can i parameterize which property file is being read by the base case and pass the filename or environment name in the command that executes the maven project ?

Comment: You can parameterize the file details and could read using System.getProperty("environment") after making pom.xml changes to support the same -- <property><name>environment</name><value>${environment}</value></property> in the sure-fire plug in configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
<property>
<name>environment</name>
<value>${environment}</value>
</property>

BaseClass--
String filename=System.getProperty("environment"); 
String PropertyFilePath="\\src\\test\\java\\com\\resources\\"+filename+".properties";


Case1: When i pass the value here as 'stage'. 
My test test base class will read the 'stage.properties' file

Case2: When i pass the value here as 'test'. 
My test test base class will read the 'test.properties' file


My question is - How will i be passing the argument to <value>${environment}</value>

Comment: Use it under VM options in the Dun/Debug configuration -Denvironment=stage

Comment: I actually figured it out. It was kinda easy. 
I used —mvn test -Denvironment=stage — this exectutee the runner file with stage.properties. 
Thank you for the help